# I am Getting Null Pointer Exception when i try to read jdbcTemplate in method getEmployeeById

Tags: java, spring, jdbctemplate

In this Code whenever invoke storeEmployeeRecord() it reads jdbcTemplate and then it perform further steps to store the data entered by user in form but problem is with getEmployeeById() whenever i invoke this method it returns me null. I also found one issue with jdbcTemplate is that my first method is able to read it but getEmployeeById() method is not reading jdbcTemplate and diplaying it as null

```
    import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
    import java.sql.ResultSet;
    import java.sql.SQLException;
    import java.util.List;

    import org.naman.commandbean.Employee;
    import org.naman.commandbean.SearchEmployeeResult;
    import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
    import org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate;
    import org.springframework.jdbc.core.PreparedStatementSetter;
    import org.springframework.jdbc.core.RowMapper;
    import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

    @Repository
    public class EmployeeDAO {
        @Autowired
        private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

        public void setJdbcTemplate(JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate) {
            this.jdbcTemplate = jdbcTemplate;
        }


        public int storeEmployeeRecord(final Employee employee) {
            System.out.println("In storeEmployeeRecord jdbcTemplate= " + jdbcTemplate);
            final String query = "insert into EMP_TBL values(?,?,?)";

            return jdbcTemplate.update(query, new PreparedStatementSetter() {

                public void setValues(PreparedStatement ps) throws SQLException {
                    ps.setInt(1, employee.getEno());
                    ps.setString(2, employee.getName());
                    ps.setDouble(3, employee.getSalary());
                }// end setValues
            });// end update

        }// end storeEmployeeRecord


        public List<SearchEmployeeResult> getEmployeeById(final Integer eno) {
            final String QUERY_TO_RETRIEVEBY_ENO = "select * from EMP_TBL where eno=?";
            System.out.println("In DAO_________jdbcTemplate= " + jdbcTemplate);
            return jdbcTemplate.query(QUERY_TO_RETRIEVEBY_ENO, new PreparedStatementSetter() {

                public void setValues(PreparedStatement ps) throws SQLException {
                    ps.setInt(1, eno);
                    System.out.println("PreparedStatement_______value set");
                }// end PreparedStatementSetter
            }, new RowMapper<SearchEmployeeResult>() {

                public SearchEmployeeResult mapRow(ResultSet rs, int rowNum) throws SQLException {

                    SearchEmployeeResult employeeResult = new SearchEmployeeResult();
                    employeeResult.setEno(rs.getInt(1));
                    employeeResult.setName(rs.getString(2));
                    employeeResult.setSalary(rs.getDouble(3));

                    System.out.println("All the values are in SearchEmployeeResult.....returning values");
                    return employeeResult;
                }// end mapRow
            }); // end RowMapper
        }

    }// end class
```

[Error Console Preview:][1]

> This is Bean Configuration file

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource("classpath:db.properties")
public class DbConfiguration {

    @Autowired
    private Environment environment;
    @Autowired
    private DataSource dataSource;

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClassName(environment.getProperty("db.DriverClassName"));
        dataSource.setUrl(environment.getProperty("db.Url"));
        dataSource.setUsername(environment.getProperty("db.Username"));
        dataSource.setPassword((environment.getProperty("db.Password")));
        System.out.println(environment.getProperty("db.Password"));
        return dataSource;
    }// end dataSource

    @Bean
    public JdbcTemplate setJdbcTemplate() {
        return new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
    }// end JdbcTemplate
}// end class
```

> This is Service Class

```
import java.util.List;

import org.naman.commandbean.Employee;
import org.naman.commandbean.SearchEmployeeResult;
import org.naman.dao.EmployeeDAO;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

@Service
public class EmployeeService {

    @Autowired
    private EmployeeDAO employeeDAO;

    public int save(Employee employee) {
        return employeeDAO.storeEmployeeRecord(employee);
    }// end save

    public List<SearchEmployeeResult> getEmployeeById(Integer eno) {
        return new EmployeeDAO().getEmployeeById(eno);
    }// end getEmployeeById
}// end class
```

> This is Controller

```
import java.util.List;

import javax.validation.Valid;

import org.naman.commandbean.Employee;
import org.naman.commandbean.SearchEmployee;
import org.naman.commandbean.SearchEmployeeResult;
import org.naman.service.EmployeeService;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.validation.BindingResult;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;

@Controller
public class MyController {
    @Autowired
    private EmployeeService employeeService;
    @RequestMapping(path = "/store", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String displayForm(Employee employee, Model model) {

        model.addAttribute("employee", employee);
        return "employeeDataCapture";
    }

    @RequestMapping(path = "/store", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String processData(@Valid Employee employee, BindingResult errors, Model model) {
        if (errors.hasErrors()) {
            return "employeeDataCapture";
        } // end if
        int saveEmloyeeDetails = employeeService.save(employee);
        model.addAttribute("employeeData", saveEmloyeeDetails);
        return "employeeDataSuccess";
    }    
    @RequestMapping(path = "/search", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String displayAllEmployeesFrom(SearchEmployee searchEmployee, Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("searchEmployee", searchEmployee);
        return "search";
    }// end displayAllEmployeesFrom

    @RequestMapping(path = "/search", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    private String employeeSearchResult(@Valid SearchEmployee searchEmployee, BindingResult errors, Model model) {
        if (errors.hasErrors()) {
            return "search";
        } // end if

        List<SearchEmployeeResult> result = employeeService.getEmployeeById(searchEmployee.getEno());
        model.addAttribute("searchResult", result);
        return "searchResult";
    }
}//end class
```

Comment: Lose those awful "// end" comments.  They only clutter your code without adding useful information

Comment: okay i will but tell me where is the problem in my code

Comment: Try my example and let me know if you got a different exception.

Comment: Btw, please don't include an image with your exception at the bottom of your code :)

Comment: Your JdbcTemplate is null.  A spin through a debugger will tell you that.  Your wiring has to be corrected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Possibly 3 points to fix:

1. Remove your `@Autowired private DataSource dataSource;` in your `DbConfiguration`, you already have an `@Bean` method where you configure your `DataSource`
2. Remove the `setJdbcTemplate` method inside your DAO. You alread `@Autowire` it in the fields.
3. Add the `@ComponentScan(basePackages = "org.naman")` to your `DbConfiguration`. This scans for components (every class containing `@Repository` and `@Service` etc and injects the dependencies to them.

**Actual fix:**

Turn your method into this: 
`public List<SearchEmployeeResult> getEmployeeById(Integer eno) {
        return employeeDAO.getEmployeeById(eno);
    }`
    You **never** create your Beans yourself. That is what Spring is for. Your `jdbcTemplate` isn't set by Spring in `getEmployeeById`, so it is null.

Comment: @Autowired private DataSource dataSource; I think it is mandatory because jdbcTemplate is dependent on datasouce. and to use datasource outside the method i've done this

Comment: Added the 3rd point, that might be it.

Comment: No,still same problem. In my DAO class inside storeEmployeeRecord()-- it is able to read jdbcTemplate System.out.println("In storeEmployeeRecord jdbcTemplate= " + jdbcTemplate); i don't know why it is not able to read same instance variable in getEmployeeById()--- System.out.println("In DAO_________jdbcTemplate= " + jdbcTemplate);

Comment: Please add the code of your `EmployeeService` class

Comment: i have added plz have a look

Comment: I think you can also spot your mistake by now ;)

Comment: Thank's  i lot it work. :)